# RethinkDB: Cannot call `changes` on an eager stream

Tags: rethinkdb

I have a table of users who each have an array of friends.

A document in it looks something like this:

```
{
    id: "0ab43d81-b883-424a-be56-32f9ff98f7d2",
    username: "testUser1234",
    friends: [
        "04423c56-1890-4028-b38a-cb9aff7112de" ,
        "05e4e613-2131-408c-b0ae-a952f3007405" ,
        "0395ee53-8ab0-48cc-aa4e-41aad93b8737"
    ]
}
```

I want to watch for changes on a user's friends'. A query like this will get me a list of friends:

```
r.db("Test").table("Users").get("0ab43d81-b883-424a-be56-32f9ff98f7d2")("friends").map(function(id) { 
    return r.db("Test").table("Users").get(id);
})
```

But, when I try to throw a `.changes()` on the end, RethinkDB tells me that it won't work:

```
RqlRuntimeError: Cannot call `changes` on an eager stream in:
r.db("Test").table("Users").get("0ab43d81-b883-424a-be56-32f9ff98f7d2")("friends").map(function(var_19) { return r.db("Test").table("Users").get(var_19); }).changes()
```

Is there anyway to get this to work? I am afraid that my only alternative is to subscribe to the friends list (in my app) and update the subscription to the actual friends when it changes:

```
r.db("Test").table("Users").getAll(friendId1, friendId2 , friendId3, friendId4).changes()
```

Not the end of the world, but I was really excited about being able to do it entirely in the DB.

Also, can anyone explain what an "eager stream" is? I think it has something to do with lazy vs. immediate evaluation, but I had no idea how to tell what the criteria determines whether a stream is eager or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can get the query working with the following formation, inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25818047/1623877):

```
r.db("Test").table('Users').getAll(r.args(
    r.db('Test').table('Users').get("0ab43d81-b883-424a-be56-32f9ff98f7d2")('friends')
)).changes()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can attach the `.changes` before some of the transofrmations.

```
r.db("Test")
 .table("Users")
 .get("0ab43d81-b883-424a-be56-32f9ff98f7d2")
 .changes()
 .getField('new_val')('friends')
 .map(function(id) { 
   return r.db("Test").table("Users").get( id );
 })
```

Basically, every time there is a change, the `map` function is executed. At the moment, that is the only way to do this type of operations with `.changes`, but that will change in upcoming versions of RethinkDB.

Comment: Thanks, Jorge, but that still results in the "eager stream" error.

Comment: I had to add a second map (the `id` value was actually the friends array, for some reason...), but it only watched for changes on the user, but not the user's friends.